# Get file path of continuously updating file

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.path

I have found a few approaches to search for the newest file created by a user in a directory, but I need to determine if an easier approach exists. Most posts on this topics work in some instances or have major hurdles, so I am hoping to unmuddy the water.

I am having difficulty looking through a growing file system, as well as bringing more users in with more potential errors.

I get data from a Superlogics Winview CP 32 for a continuously streaming system. On each occasion of use of the system, I have the operator input a unique identifier for the file name containing a few of the initial conditions of the system we need to track. I would like to get that file name with no help from the operator/user.

Eventually, the end goal is to pare down a list of files I want to search, filtered based on keys, so my first instinct was to use only matching file types, trim all folders in a pathway into a list, and sort based on max timestamp. I used some pretty common functions from these pages:

```
def fileWalkIn(path='.',matches=[],filt='*.csv'): # Useful for walking through a given directory
    """Iterates through all files under the given path using a filter."""
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, filt):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)

def getRecentFile(path='.',matches=[],filt='*.dat'):
    rr = max(fileWalkIn(path=path,matches=matches,filt=filt), key=os.path.getmtime)
    return rr
```

This got me far, but is rather bulky and slow, which means I cannot do this repeatedly if I want to explore the files that match, lest I have to carry around a bulky list of the matching files.

Ideally, I will be able to process the data on the fly, executing and printing live while it writes, so this approach is not usable in that instance.

I borrowed from these pages a new approach by alex-martelli, which does not use a filter, gives the option of giving files, opposed to directories, is much slimmer than fileWalkIn, and works quicker if using the timestamp.

```
def all_subdirs_of(b='.'): # Useful for walking through a given directory
    # Create hashable list of files or directories in the parent directory
    results = []
    for d in os.listdir(b):

        bd = os.path.join(b, d)
        if os.path.isfile(bd):     
            results.append(bd)
        elif os.path.isdir(bd): 
            results.append(bd)

    # return both
    return results

def newest(path='.'):

    rr = max(all_subdirs_of(b=path), key=os.path.getmtime)
    return rr

def getActiveFile(newFile ='.'):

    while os.path.exists(newFile):

        newFile = newest(newFile)
        if os.path.isfile(newFile): 

            return newFile
        else:
            if newFile:
                continue
            else:
                return newFile
```

This gets me the active file in a directory much more quickly, but only if no other files have written since launching my data collection. I can see all kinds of problems here and need some help determining if I have gone down a rabbit hole and there is a more simple solution, like testing file sizes, or whether a more cohesive solution with less potential snags exists.

I found other answers for different languages (java, how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file), but would need something in Python. I have explored functions like [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) and [win32](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/browse-for-a-folder.html), but both require steep learning curves, and I feel like I am either very close, or need to change my paradigm entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dircache might speed up the second approach a bit. It's a wrapper around listdir that checks the directory timestamp and only re-reads directory contents if there's been a change.

Beyond that you really need something that listens to file system events. A quick google turned up two pip packages, pyinotify for Linux only and watchdog.

Hope this helps.